# I can Euler-sum $\sqrt{\ln(1)}-\sqrt{\ln(2)}+\sqrt{\ln(3)}-\cdots$. But how can I do $\sqrt{\ln(1)}+\sqrt{\ln(2)}+\sqrt{\ln(3)}+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, riemann-zeta, divergent-series, fractional-calculus

This is also related to an older thread in MSE ("[what is the half derivative of zeta at zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375710/what-is-the-half-derivative-of-zeta-at-s-0-and-how-to-compute-it)") .

One of the possible steps in the problem of that thread was to evaluate the series

$$s_a=\eta^{(0.5)}(0) = î \small{\left(\sqrt{\ln(1)}-\sqrt{\ln(2)}+\sqrt{\ln(3)}-\sqrt{\ln(4)} \cdots \right) \underset{\mathfrak E}{\approx}} - 0.347006596200 \, î $$ as the (regularized by Euler-summation $\mathfrak E$) value for the half-derivative of the alternating zeta (or "Dirichlet's eta"). Note, that the additional imaginary factor $î$ is due to the fact, that we had originally negative values under the square-root terms. In the following I'll leave this factor out for convenience.

***Q:* But how can I do** the nonalternating series $$ s_p=\zeta^{(0.5)}(0)= î \small{ \left( \sqrt{\ln(1)}+\sqrt{\ln(2)}+\sqrt{\ln(3)}+\sqrt{\ln(4)}+ \cdots \right)} \underset{\mathfrak ???}{\approx} ??? $$ 
$\qquad \qquad$ I don't see so far any possibility for instance in the sense of L. Euler's famous $\eta() \to \zeta() $ - conversion.

---

**[update]**: what I've additionally just done was to apply a procedure to find the/a formal power series for the problem of finite sums of consecutive terms.

The procedure is that of the approximation of the Neumann-series of the Carleman-matrix for the function $f(x) = \sqrt{\ln(\exp(x^2)+1)}$ which is the iterative transfer function which produces the term of the series for index $n+1$ from the term at index $n$.

***I'll explain this now in more detail:***

For the procedure which is also known with the name "indefinite summation" we need first a function, which generates the terms of the series to be summed as ***iterates*** of itself. What function can transfer $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$ to $\sqrt{\ln(x+1)}$? This is $f(x)$ as given above, because for instance it gives for $z= \sqrt{\ln(5)}$ the result $f( z) = \sqrt{\ln(6)}$ and $f°^2( z) = \sqrt{\ln(7)}$ and so on.
So we can formally write the series $$ s_p  =î \cdot ( z + f(z) + f°^2(z) + f°^3(z) + ... ) \qquad \qquad \text{ with } z=\sqrt{\ln(1)}=0 $$
An approach which I've exercised a couple of times is to implement $f()$ by a Carlemanmatrix based on $f()$'s formal powerseries. That powerseries is
$$ \mathcal {\text{Taylor}} (f(x)) \approx \small  0.83255461 + 0.30028060 x^2 + 0.020918484 x^4 - 0.0075447481 x^6  + ... $$

Let now $ C = \text{carleman}(f) $ be the Carlemanmatrix for $f(x)$ then the dotproduct of a vector $V(x)=[1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...]$ with $C$ gives $V(x) \cdot C= V(f(x))$ by definition, and if we look at the second column of $C$ only we have $V(x) \cdot C_{0..\infty,1} = f(x)$ at least as formal powerseries, and if it is convergent for small $x$ we can also evaluate numerically.

Now the idea of the Neumann-series comes into play. As $V(x) \cdot C_{0..\infty,1} = f(x)$ we should formally also have $V(x) \cdot C^2_{0..\infty,1} = f°^2(x)$,  $V(x) \cdot C^3_{0..\infty,1} = f°^3(x)$ and so on, such that we make the ansatz:
$$ V(z) \cdot ( C^0 + C^1 + C^2 + C^3 + ... )_{0..\infty,1} \overset?= z + f°(z) + f°^2(z) + f°^3(z) + ... $$
and the key-observation is here, that we have in the parenthese of the lhs the ***geometric series*** of the matrix $C$ (such a construct is also called "Neumann-series"). We can surely expect, that this is no proper sum, but with some examples of ***alternating geometric series*** instead I could get meaningful approximations when using empirical approximations to $B = (I+C)^{-1}$ and then approximate for instance $V(z) \underset{\mathfrak E}\cdot B_{0..\infty,1} \approx z - f(z) + f°^2(z) - ... + ...$ where $\mathfrak E$ means Eulersummation in the dotproduct if needed.

This is not so simple and straightforward for the ***non-alternating*** geometric series. As the Carlemanmatrix of any function has the eigenvalue $1$ (at least once) by construction we would run into $\frac 10$ and cannot immediately try the approximation with finitely truncated matrices $A = ( I - C)^{-1}$. One of the workarounds, which gives sometimes meaningful results is, to omit the first column of $(I - C)$ which gives then some result, but where the first row is then systematically missing/unknown.

*Remark: a case where this workaround is successful is the problem of the sum-of-like-powers where the Carlemanmatrix is the upper-triangular Pascalmatrix $P$ . The removal of the empty first column in $ Q = (I - P)_{0..(n-1),1..n} $ allows inversion and provides the matrix $Q^{-1}$ of coefficients, with which Faulhaber had solved the summing-of-like-powers-problem. The same ansatz was also tried as far as I know by two authors for solving the extension of tetration to real iteration heights. I've similarly attempted some other series-problems with such "iteration-series" of iterated functions $f°^h(x)$ and their according Neumann-series with meaningful approximations*

So I've now tested $_n Q = (I - C)_{0..n-1,1..n}$ with increasing $n$ and computed $\,_nA^* = \,_n Q^{-1} $ and made $\,_nA$ by inserting the unknown first row in $\,_nA^*$ 
The top-left of the heuristically approximated matrix $\,_nA$ is $$\small \,_nA_{0..16,0..1}=\begin{bmatrix} 
 ?? & ?? \\ 
 0 & 1 \\ 
 -1 & -0.662055270527 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{2!} & -0.561866397242 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{3!} & -0.249581408503 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{4!} & -0.0755503260124 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{5!} & -0.0172091887343 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{6!} & -0.00315760368955 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{7!} & -0.000499047959470 \\ 
 0 & 0 \\ 
 -\frac1{8!} & -0.0000687607442729 \\
  ... & ...
 \end{bmatrix} $$
Using the coefficients of the first column for a power series in $x$ building the function $a_0(x)$ we get
$$ a_0( \sqrt{\ln(n_1)})-a_0( \sqrt{\ln(n_2)}) = n_2 - n_1 $$
which indicates the sum of the $(f°^k(n_1))^0$ - and which is just counting the terms.

Using the coefficients $a_{k,1}$ of the second column for a power series in $x$ building the function $a_1(x)$ we get the finite sum of the function at consecutive arguments:
$$ a_1( \sqrt{\ln(n_1)})-a_1( \sqrt{\ln(n_2)}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty  (\sqrt{\ln(n_1)}^k - \sqrt{\ln(n_2)}^k )a_{k,1}  = \sum_{k=n_1}^{n_2-1} \sqrt{\ln (k)}  $$
which indicates the sum of the $f°^k(n_1)$ which is the desired finite sums $s_p$ for  the required terms to a very good (and seemingly arbitrary) numerical approximation.
***------ End of lengthy explanation***

> Q: However - I'm missing the first coefficient for the second power series $a_1(x)$ . That should just contain the representative value for the infinite sum of $\sqrt{\ln(k)} $ with $k=1 ... \infty$

Comment: Very interesting sum, but I can only half understand what is going on.

Comment: What do you need? What a "half-derivative" is?

Comment: No, I understand what fractional derivatives are, but familiar with anything starting from the **UPDATE** section, which is half the post.

Comment: I see... Well, this is a method which needs some more background I'm afraid. The idea is, to derive a solution by converting the problem of a powerseries into one containing iterates of a function, which I've applied several times to similar problems. A related link is http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/BernoulliForLogSums.pdf where I try to explain what I'm also doing here. Perhaps a more basic introduction is this which deals with the sums-of-like-powers-problem with this method: http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf , the $\eta()$-function.

Comment: @simpleArt : This is not a complete "private" method, one can find application of this under the term "indefinite summation" and there are question&answers here in MSE as well as in MO which cover this subject. Unfortunately I've no good idea at the moment for a good historical text, maybe the Euler-Maclaurin-formula is a usable example, but I've nothing at the top of my head in the moment...

Comment: Have you tried to apply a [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation)?

Comment: @SimpleArt: actually no time due to courses. Let's see next week.

Comment: :-P ok. :D can't wait to take the classes your probably taking.  At least the math ones.

Comment: @SimpleArt: :-)  (It's introductory empirical statistics for social workers which I have to give; I could math only make a hobby... )

Answer (score 1):

One form of the [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) is done as follows:

$$\sum_{n\ge1}^\Re f(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)-\int_1^Nf(t)\ dt$$

For our case,

$$\sum_{n\ge1}^\Re\sqrt{\ln(n)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sqrt{\ln(n)}-\int_1^N\sqrt{\ln(t)}\ dt\approx1.6$$

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll look at it next week. *( Hmm, doing this in Pari/GP gives a likely result $\gt 1.6$ by `N=1000000;sum(k=1,N,sqrt(log(k)))-intnum(x=1,N,sqrt(log(x)))` (with 200 digits internal precision) giving `= 1.65764...`  and from $N=10^2$ to $N=10^6$ giving around 0.2 more for each step in the exponent with slowly decreasing tendency)*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms with my low tech, I could only manage like $n=60$k or so...

Comment: I think it grows around the rate of about $\sqrt{\ln(n)}$, so I might fix this to the constant term in the Euler-Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: Sorry, forgot completely this question/your answer after the courses... I'll look at your answer again from tomorrow (It's night already here, my pillow is waiting...)

Comment: XD Same, forgetting *and* looking at my bed.  :D

Comment: Also totally random, but you might like [this PDF](https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/5bf619d1-8c79-4010-9d87-1c9d34fa50b6) I just finished making.

Comment: Hmm, after many experiments with this I still don't see any path to more conclusive results than in my first comment ...

Comment: :-( That sucks.  Well, I hope we get results eventually.

Comment: Late comment: I tried your sum/integral-formula again, and only with changing the upper limit of the integral to $N+1/2$ instead of $N$ I seem to get convergence; tried it in steps of $2^j$ : `N=100*2^10;` `su=sum(k=1,N,sqrt(log(k)))-intnum(t=1,N+1/2,sqrt(log(t)))` $\to$  `su = -0.200824720791` with seemingly convergence when the exponent at `100*2^j` is increased... But I don't have any idea what to make with this...

Comment: Another late comment: yesterday I looked again at your linked pdf. I got the impression you might like this article on mine about summation of ***really*** diverging series, the short form in http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/10_4_Powertower_article.pdf and a more explanative form in http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/10_4_Powertower.pdf (A bit more of this on my tetration-pages http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs) The articles are very early discussions of mine where I often lacked even correct naming of things, but you might like the explorative style. Perhaps I'll improve some day...

Comment: Thanks for the interesting reads, will check them out.

Comment: Looking back on it, it's probably because the summation and integral line up best if we use $f(n)\approx\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}f(x)~\mathrm dx$, which explains the convergence.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with this series it has a pole at z=1
[image]